# Define function inside const react native

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, methods, constants

I typed the code below in react-native and it returned the following error

> undefined is not a function `(evaluating 'this.createPiece('T')')`

I don't know how to define it. Please help me

```
    const player = {
    pos: {x: 5, y: 5},
    matrix: this.createPiece('T'),
};
```

and the createPiece method:

```
createPiece(type) {
    if (type == 'T') {
        return [
            [0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 0],
        ];
    }
}
```

[full code](https://anotepad.com/notes/fs36an)

Comment: Not sure if this is your actual code, but if it is, it's not valid. For example the function declaration is invalid

Comment: then how to declare it??
it is my question right??

Comment: It probably needs the `function` keyword before its name (if it's not a class method). Also it does not return a value for all its inputs, only for `'T'`

Comment: Can you post the whole class? We need to see the scopes of your functions in order to help.

Comment: Please post your whole code. Where is the `const player` initialisation located, and on which object is that method defined?

Comment: I've added the whole class. hope can help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  this.createPiece = function (type) {
        if (type== 'T') {
            return [
                [0, 0, 0],
                [1, 1, 1],
                [0, 1, 0],
            ];
        }
    };
    const player = {
        pos: {x: 5, y: 5},
        matrix: this.createPiece('T'),
    };
```

Comment: it still error, same with my code. try to see the full code (as i edited on my post above)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer:

- React Native:

Just use **state** instead of **const**

- React:

Just use **const**, it more global